# Unexpected output using Pythons' ternary operator in combination with lambda

Tags: python, boolean, conditional-operator

I have a specific situation in which I would like to do the following (actually it is more involved than this, but I reduced the problem to the essence):

```
>>> (lambda e: 1)(0) if (lambda e: True)(0) else (lambda e: 2)(0)
True
```

which is a difficult way of writing:

```
>>> 1 if True else 2
1
```

but in reality '1','True' and '2' are additional expressions that get evaluated and which require the variable 'e', which I set to '0' for this simplified code example.

Note the difference in output from both expressions above, although

```
>>> (lambda e: 1)(0)
1
>>> (lambda e: True)(0)
True
>>> (lambda e: 2)(0)
2
```

The funny thing is that this is a special case, because if I replace '1' by '3' I get the expected/desired result:

```
>>> (lambda e: 3)(0) if (lambda e: True)(0) else (lambda e: 2)(0)
3
```

It's even correct if I replace '1' by '0' (which could also be a special case since 1==True and 0==False)

```
>>> (lambda e: 0)(0) if (lambda e: True)(0) else (lambda e: 2)(0)
0
```

Also, if I replace 'True' by 'not False' or 'not not True', it still works:

```
>>> (lambda e: 1)(0) if (lambda e: not False)(0) else (lambda e: 2)(0)
1
>>> (lambda e: 1)(0) if (lambda e: not not True)(0) else (lambda e: 2)(0)
1
```

Another alternative formulation uses the usual if..then..else statement and does not produce the error:

```
>>> if (lambda e: True)(0):
    (lambda e: 1)(0)
else:
    (lambda e: 2)(0)

1
```

What explains this behavior? How can I solve this behavior in a nice way (avoid to use 'not not True' or something?

Thanks!

PS: the question revealed a bug in Python, see https://bugs.python.org/issue25843 for the issue tracking.

Comment: `(lambda e: 1)` is just a function that always returns `1` when called. `(lambda e: 3)` returns `3`. I don't see any oddities or special cases. Can you clarify what the problem is? I know this is a toy example, but there is no reason to do a lambda like this... the lambda is just an expression that can be added directly to the `if`.

Comment: I am working through a book on programming languages. I am writing a piece of software that will output Python-code in a string. So basically, the piece of code that I'm showing is put inside " " and assigned to a variable. This is supposed to be recursive, so the values '1', 'True' and '0' could in general be other expressions that get evaluated. In some cases the expression depends on the variable 'e', so hence it is passed as an argument in general. Therefore I use `(lambda e: 1)(0)` instead of `1`, because the output is not known in general. I hope this makes it clearer...

Comment: Note the fact that the lambda-expression is immediately evaluated, so `(lambda e: 1)(0)` and not `(lambda e: 1)`.

Comment: Okay, I'm dope=slapping myself. The problem is that the example returns `True` when the lambda returns `1`. Got it!

Comment: Interestingly, `(lambda e: 1)(0) if (lambda e: False)(0) else (lambda e: 1)(0)` (meaning the else clause runs) returns `1`, not `True`.

Comment: And if I define `def a(x): return 1`, `a(0) if (lambda e: False)(0) else (lambda e: 1)(0)` also returns `1`. Lambda and if..else are not playing nicely together.

Comment: Yes, the combination lambda and if..else seems to be the problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe. Does the actual line of code you posted produce the erroneous result you posted? And what Python version are you on?

Comment: I have just re-checked each line of code for its output in my python shell. It is as posted above. I have Python 3.4.3 in IDLE.

Comment: Oh geeze, [you're right](http://ideone.com/nXDGl8), what the heck?

Comment: [Something is very wrong with Python 3's behavior here.](http://ideone.com/KWDNfi) - EDIT: and something is wrong with Ideone, because the output in that link doesn't correspond to that version of the code.

Comment: @user2357112: what does dis.dis(f) do in your above test?

Comment: @tvo: It's supposed to show decompiler output for the function `f`, but Ideone is showing the output from a completely different test I ran. (I believe that output is for `print((lambda e: 1)(0), (lambda e: True)(0))`.)

Comment: By the way, I just tested the same code on Ideone for (regular) Python, and the answer is correct, i.e. "1". So there is a difference between Python and Python 3.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think I figured out why the bug is happening, and why your repro is Python 3 specific.

[Code objects do equality comparisons by value](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/codeobject.c#l535), rather than by pointer, strangely enough:

```
static PyObject *
code_richcompare(PyObject *self, PyObject *other, int op)
{
    ...

    co = (PyCodeObject *)self;
    cp = (PyCodeObject *)other;

    eq = PyObject_RichCompareBool(co->co_name, cp->co_name, Py_EQ);
    if (eq <= 0) goto unequal;
    eq = co->co_argcount == cp->co_argcount;
    if (!eq) goto unequal;
    eq = co->co_kwonlyargcount == cp->co_kwonlyargcount;
    if (!eq) goto unequal;
    eq = co->co_nlocals == cp->co_nlocals;
    if (!eq) goto unequal;
    eq = co->co_flags == cp->co_flags;
    if (!eq) goto unequal;
    eq = co->co_firstlineno == cp->co_firstlineno;
    if (!eq) goto unequal;

    ...
```

In Python 2, `lambda e: True` does a global name lookup and `lambda e: 1` loads a constant `1`, so the code objects for these functions don't compare equal. In Python 3, `True` is a keyword and both lambdas load constants. Since `1 == True`, the code objects are sufficiently similar that all the checks in `code_richcompare` pass, and the code objects compare the same. (One of the checks is for line number, so the bug only appears when the lambdas are on the same line.)

[The bytecode compiler calls `ADDOP_O(c, LOAD_CONST, (PyObject*)co, consts)`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Python/compile.c#l1473) to create the `LOAD_CONST` instruction that loads a lambda's code onto the stack, and `ADDOP_O` uses a dict to keep track of objects it's added, in an attempt to save space on stuff like duplicate constants. It has some handling to distinguish things like `0.0`, `0`, and `-0.0` that would otherwise compare equal, but it wasn't expected that they'd ever need to handle equal-but-inequivalent code objects. The code objects aren't distinguished properly, and the two lambdas end up sharing a single code object.

By replacing `True` with `1.0`, we can reproduce the bug on Python 2:

```
>>> f1, f2 = lambda: 1, lambda: 1.0
>>> f2()
1
```

I don't have Python 3.5, so I can't check whether the bug is still present in that version. I didn't see anything in the bug tracker about the bug, but I could have just missed the report. If the bug is still there and hasn't been reported, it should be reported.

Comment: Still the same in 3.5. Looks like candidate for a bug report.

Comment: @user2357112 : How does this explain the behavior that is observed in my question? You say `lambda e:1` loads a constant `1`, but why would this expression then return `True`? Thanks.

Comment: @tvo: Its code object compares equal to that of `lambda e: True`, and the compiler ends up reusing `lambda e: True`'s code object for `lambda e: 1` when it really shouldn't.

Comment: @user2357112: Hi, I added an additional code example to the question using the usual if statement. This does not show the problem. Is that consistent with your explanation?

Comment: @user2357112: I just checked: the same conflict is occurring between `(lambda e: False)` and `(lambda e: 0)`, which supports your answer. Did you report a bug?

Comment: @tvo: The `if` statement example is consistent with this explanation, since the lambdas are on different lines. I haven't filed a bug report.

Comment: Ok, I just filed a bug report about this, linking to SO.

Comment: It is still present in 3.5.

Comment: @Pedro: Fixed in those branches, at least, but as of this writing, no actual release incorporates the fixes yet. If you go download Python 2.7 or Python 3.5 and try `f1, f2 = lambda: 1, lambda: 1.0; f2()` right now, it'll still give you the wrong answer. The next bugfix releases should incorporate the fix, and 3.6 will have it whenever 3.6 comes out.