# Python 3 Asyncio coroutine equality

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

```
class A:
  async def func2(self):
    pass
```

In a unit test I want to assert that a certain coroutine gets passed with an equality check i.e

`arg1 == func2()`

However, couroutines have an address associated with them:

`'<coroutine object Class.func1 at 0x12341234>'`

Is there a canonical way to test coroutine equality? Should I just regex the `__str__` representation of the coroutine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a bit better than comparing `__repr__`s -- you can compare the underlying code object:

```
class A:
    async def func2(self):
        pass

a = A()
x = a.func2()
y = a.func2()

print(x == y)                   # False
print(x.cr_code is y.cr_code)   # True
```

Comment: A few things to keep in mind: first, beware of false positives or false negatives from things like decorators. Second, code object `==` is not by identity, which can lead to and [has lead to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34100732/unexpected-output-using-pythons-ternary-operator-in-combination-with-lambda) really weird bugs. It's probably not an issue here, but still, `is` is more appropriate than `==`.

Comment: @user2357112 thanks made the edit, now off to browse the repo to see how `__eq__` (or the c equivalent) implemented for code objects.

Comment: @user2357112 [I'll just take your word for it... :)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/codeobject.c#L630)

Comment: Consider the case where the same an async function is called with different arguments. Bare code object comparison is not enough.

Comment: @AndrewSvetlov whether "it's not enough" depends on what you care about, no?  If you just care about whether the same async function was referenced (or if the function accepts no arguments) then this should suffice.  This approach is just like comparing `x.func is y.func` for `partial` objects.

Comment: Well, from my perspective a coroutine comparison is a mental exercise. I never used it in my code and cannot imagine where it is needed. Comparison of *async functions* makes more sense though, but I never restored it from coroutines (or any awaitable object).